# Having issues in matching pattern

Tags: android, pattern-matching

I am working on Music Downloader application and in that I have to read entire web page of a website and then need to show result of it. So I read that source code of an entire web. Now song name and URL of that can be as below in html page :

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="right_song">
    <div style="font-size:15px;"><b>Name of song</b></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;">
    <div style="float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;">
    <div style="float:left;"><a href="link of song" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a>
```

So I thought of using Pattern of this and then matching it to get name and URL.

**I made pattern as below :**

```
<div id=\"right_song\">
<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>([^<]*)</b></div>
<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>
<div style=\"float:left;\">
<div style=\"float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;\">
<div style=\"float:left;\"><a href=\"([^\"]*)\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:green;\">Download</a>
```

But it always return as No Pattern found so where I am going wrong.

Please guide me to make it perfect.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't try using a regular expression on such a large amount of data. Use an HTML parser, not a regex. You're using the wrong tool for the job - like using a razor blade when you should be using a screwdriver.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart I am reading entire web page and then checking to find pattern to get songs. As i want different layout for application will html parser provide me different view for application?

Answer (score 0):

purely based on the example. seems like a termination line problem + SO's 4 spaces quotes..

```
/<div id=\"right_song\">[\r\n\t\ ]+<div style=\"font-size:15px;\"><b>([^<]*)</b></div>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div style=\"float:left;\">[\r\n\t\ ]+<div style=\"float:left; height:27px; font-size:13px; padding-top:2px;\">[\r\n\t\ ]+<div style=\"float:left;\"><a href=\"([^\"]*)\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:green;\">Download</a>/
```

however there's a shorter/safer way of grep'ing patterns which allows for the 3rd party to change subtle css details

```
/<div[^>]+>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div[^>]+><b>([^<]*)</b></div>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div[^>]+></div>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div[^>]+>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div[^>]+>[\r\n\t\ ]+<div[^>]+><a href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]+>Download</a>/
```